# writing to rfid

Tags: c#

```
    public void writeToCard2(string sourceText, string cardType)
    {
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;

        int itemLength = sourceText.Split(',').Length;
        sourceText = itemLength.ToString() + "," + sourceText + ",";
        byte[] dataByteArray = Encoding.GetEncoding(932).GetBytes(sourceText);
        //textBox2.Text = BitConverter.ToString(dataByteArray);

        int dataByteLength = dataByteArray.Length;
        int writeLength = dataByteLength + 11;
        byte[] writeByteArray = new byte[writeLength];

        writeByteArray[0] = 0x02;//STX
        writeByteArray[1] = 0x00;//アドレス
        writeByteArray[2] = 0x78;//コマンド
        writeByteArray[3] = Convert.ToByte(dataByteLength + 4);//データ長
        writeByteArray[4] = 0xa1;//詳細コマンド
        writeByteArray[5] = 0x00;//書き込み開始ブロック番号
        writeByteArray[6] = Convert.ToByte(dataByteLength);//書き込みバイト数
        for (int i = 0; i < dataByteLength; i++)
        {
            writeByteArray[i + 7] = dataByteArray[i];//書き込みデータ
        }
        writeByteArray[dataByteLength + 7] = 0x40;//オプションフラグ
        writeByteArray[dataByteLength + 8] = 0x03;//ETX
        byte sum = 0x00;
        for (int i = 0; i <= dataByteLength + 8; i++)
        {
            sum += writeByteArray[i];
        }
        writeByteArray[dataByteLength + 9] = sum;//SUM値
        writeByteArray[dataByteLength + 10] = 0x0d;//CR

        //string tempStr = BitConverter.ToString(writeByteArray);

        //port.Write(writeByteArray, 0, writeByteArray.Length);
        serialPort1.Write(writeByteArray, 0, writeByteArray.Length);

        writeCardType = cardType;

        Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
    }
```

the above method writes data on an rfid tag in the line

```
serialPort1.Write(writeByteArray, 0, writeByteArray.Length);
```

writeByteArray is the size of the data which is exceeding the limit of the *RFID* tag, my boss said convert it to `ascii` code and then write to *RFID*.

Will this help can this conversion reduce size of data?

Is there any other way round withoud using a different *RFID* tag?

Comment: The limitation is the amount of data the tag can store, not the protocol you use to talk to the RFID controller.  That's a hard design limit, nothing you can do to change it beyond throwing all your tags away and getting a different kind.  You'll have to find a smarter way to encode the information into the available bits, like using one byte to encode two digits.

Comment: @HansPassant yeah i m trying to look for that smarter way but for now i can't find one....changing type of rfid is one of the options but it will increase the cost of the project

Answer (score 1):

Your boss said to convert to *ASCII* cause device reads information *byt per byte*. I worked with that devices and that is usual way they read the data stream passed to them.

There is not any *allocation* benefit in this, cause the size of the data remains the same, what changes is information rapresentation. That is.